# I overload an operator*() function for calculating the sum of two matrices,but the compiler prompts for this error

Tags: c++

I map the matrix to a one-dimensional array using the row pivot order

```
template<class T>
matrix<T> matrix<T>::operator*(const matrix<T>& m) const {
    if (theCols != m.theRows) throw exception();
    matrix<T> w(theRows, m.theCols);
    for (int i = 1; i <= theRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < m.theCols; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= theCols; k++) {
                w[(i - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1] += element[(i - 1)*theCols + j - 1] * m.element[(k - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

> error:Binary "[" :" matrix "does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to a predefined operator

What happened to my code?

Comment: Can you show also `operator[]`?

Comment: Do your `matrix` template have an overloaded `operator[]` function?

Comment: Oh, and instead of starting your loops with `1` and then subtracting `1` everywhere the index is used, why not simply start the loops on `0`?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem. Most likely you wanted `j<=m.theCols;`

Comment: also `w[(i - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1]` looks suspicious. Should it not be `w.theCols`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo here:

> ```
>            w[(i - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1] += element[(i - 1)*theCols + j - 1] * m.element[(k - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1];
>   //       ^^^^
> ```

You probably mean:

```
            w.element[(i - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1] += element[(i - 1)*theCols + j - 1] * m.element[(k - 1)*m.theCols + j - 1];
//           ^^^^^^^^
```